# Low noise transistor series pass voltage regulator

Tags: power-supply, transistors, bjt, noise, oscillation

I'm currently working on a series pass voltage regulator within LTSpice.
Here is this circuit:

[image: my_circuit]

I have read that these circuits are prone the oscillating and being unstable? This is one concern, the next is there is very little current travailing though the zener diode (170µA, equates to 2mW.) to hold regulation. I know its common to include another resistor from the input voltage to the cathode of ZD1 to combat this, or maybe reduce the value of R1 and R2. Both increase ripple on the output considerably, and I need this supply to be a quiet as possible as it will be used to power high-gain audio circuits.

- What are the down sides of removing the zener and just keep R3 and R4 which will be a multi-turn potentiometer?
- Will this be reliable and stable? even with large capacitance on the output?
- How can LTSpice tell me the ripple rejection in dB?

Thankyou :)

Comment: With a \$300\Omega\$ load, what is the current through ZD1? Could you add that to the question description?

Comment: You can put a resistor from the OUTPUT of the supply to the zener diode to increase its bias current. That supply is clean so it won't increase ripple.

Comment: @Kevin White just simulated that and seems a good solution :) only question is why isn't that more commonly done?

Comment: @It only works if the output can be guaranteed to be above the zener voltage, wouldn't work for an adjustable supply for example. There can also be startup issues as initially the output voltage is zero so no bias for the zener. You may need to put a diode in series with the resistor from the output to the zener to avoid the same problem.